# codeigniter session user data setting

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

i want to set user data in session. i am able to set email in session data as i am getting it from login form.
But i dont know how to get all details from database and set to session. here is my code

Controller:

```
public function login_validation() {

    // get form input
    $email = $this->input->post("email");
    $password = $this->input->post("password");

    // form validation

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "Email-ID", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "Password", "trim|required");

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        // validation fail
        $this->load->view('admin/login');
    }
    else
    {
        // check for user credentials
        $this->load->model('site_model');
        $uresult = $this->site_model->get_user($email, $password);
        $data["results"]=$this->site_model->getdata_user($email);
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $fname = $row['fname'];

        }

        if (count($uresult) > 0)
        {

            $data = array(                      
                'email' => $email,
                'fname' => $fname,
                'lname' => $lname,  
                'pre'=>$pre,
                'is_logged_in' => 1                         
            );

            // set session
            $this->session->sess_expiration = '0';// will not expire
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);

            redirect("admin/index");
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Wrong Email-ID or Password!</div>');
            $this->load->view('admin/login');
        }
    }

}
```

The model:

```
function getdata_user($email)
{
    $query= $this->db->get_where("users", array("email"=>$email));

    return $query->result();

}
```

there are some fileds in users table:  fname,lname  that i want to set to session.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the query builder class. 
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Using this resource you should be able to construct some code that reads the columns in the database.

Example on how to select columns with a where clause.

```
$this->db->select('fname, lname'); 
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('email', $email);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: can you please help me with my code. please :) i am new to codeigniter.

Comment: i got the model part.  how to pass this data to controller then set it to session. please watch my code. thank you

Comment: function getdata_user($email) { $query= $this->db->get_where("users", array("email"=>$email));

                    return $query->result();


                }

Comment: function getdata_user($email) { $query= $this->db->get_where("users", array("email"=>$email));

                    return $query->result();


                }

this is my model and this is fetching data from users table for specific user.
Now how to use this data in controller.

Answer (score 0):

1.)First of all you will call your db queries from controller:

$data = $this->Modal_name->getdata();

2.)Modal Part is here:

```
$this->db->select('fname, lname');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('email', $email) ;
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

// By above code you will get all the entries with the email id you want in array format and the array will be returned to the controller and stored in the $data variable.

3.) Set this variable as session value:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('all_data', $data);
```

//Here, you have stored all returned values in the session.

4.)The way you can access the values:
 //All the values:

```
$this->session->userdata('all_data');
```

//Value for some particular column:

```
$this->session->userdata['all_data']['column_name'];
```

//If you want to add some, particular column to the session:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('all_data',$data['column_name']);
```

**Most important thing: Don't forget to load the session library, otherwise it won't work**

Answer (score 0):

try this

set model function

```
     public function getdata_user($email)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('email', $email) ;
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

in controller function

```
    public function login_validation() {

    // get form input
    $email = $this->input->post("email");
    $password = $this->input->post("password");

    // form validation

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "Email-ID", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "Password", "trim|required");

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        // validation fail
        $this->load->view('admin/login');
    }
    else
    {
        // check for user credentials
        $this->load->model('site_model');
        $uresult = $this->site_model->get_user($email, $password);
        $results=$this->site_model->getdata_user($email);

            if ($results) {
    $sess_array = array();
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $sess_array = array(
            'email' => $row->email,
            'fname' => $row->fname,
            'lname' => $row->lname,
            'pre' => $row->pre,
            'id' => $row->id,
            );
        $this->session->set_userdata('$sess_array);
    }
    return TRUE;


            redirect("admin/index");
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Wrong Email-ID or Password!</div>');
            $this->load->view('admin/login');
        }
    }

}
```